# How to enqueue a script with Timber / Twig | Why is this not working?

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

Trying to figure out why this is not working, based on https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/750

From the `Timber` starter theme, in my `functions.php`

```php
    /** This is where you can add your own functions to twig.
     *
     * @param string $twig get extension.
     */
    public function add_to_twig($twig)
    {
        $twig->addFunction(new Timber\Twig_Function('add_script', function () {
            echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js';
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',  function () {
                wp_register_script(
                  'script',
                  get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js',
                  [],
                  '0.01'
                );
                wp_enqueue_script('script');
            });
        }));

        //  $twig->addExtension( new Twig\Extension\StringLoaderExtension() );
        //  $twig->addFilter( new Twig\TwigFilter( 'myfoo', array( $this, 'myfoo' ) ) );

        return $twig;
    }
```

And then at the end of `base.twig` I add `{{ add_script() }}`

The route is correct (`script.js` is in the same folder than `functions.php`, and I can see the file if I copy-paste the url) and the `echo` works, so the twig code is executed

However, the script is not added / executed, it contains a simple `console.log('hey')` and nothing is outputed in the dev console

What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

First, I don't need the `add_action` hook (I added it since without it it didn't seem to work)

```php
    /** This is where you can add your own functions to twig.
     *
     * @param string $twig get extension.
     */
    public function add_to_twig($twig)
    {
        $twig->addFunction(new Timber\Twig_Function('add_script', function () {
            echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js';
                wp_register_script(
                  'script',
                  get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js',
                  [],
                  '0.01'
                );
                wp_enqueue_script('script');
        }));

        //  $twig->addExtension( new Twig\Extension\StringLoaderExtension() );
        //  $twig->addFilter( new Twig\TwigFilter( 'myfoo', array( $this, 'myfoo' ) ) );

        return $twig;
    }
```

Second, in `base.twig` the `{{ add_script() }}` has to go before the `{{ function('wp_footer') }}`, as actually said in the github link of the question

https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/750

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/